# Filtered item selection in bash

Tags: bash, dialog

I am making a script which needs to let the user select an item from a big list (roughly 1000+ items).

Considering the size of the list, the user needs to somehow search and filter it.

Currently I am using [dmenu](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dmenu), but I would like to make it all contained inside the terminal window and not require X.

I've looked around for tools like dialog or whiptail, but they don't seem to provide any means of filtering or otherwise using such a long list of items.

Am I overlooking something, or is this not really possible to do with the currently common tools?

Comment: @John1024 iselect looks close to what I'm looking for! But it's missing the search/filter function. If there won't be any alternative, I will use that along with a filter on the script side I think.